# Why would starships have intake manifolds?

Tags: star-trek, engineering

In Enterprise 3x14, the captain vents plasma from a shuttle pod to escape from some insectoids.  He smugly claims, "the plasma got into their intake manifolds and is overheating their engines".

AFAIK, intake manifolds are used to channel air into an aspirated fuel engine, what would they do on a spaceship flying in vacuum?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There *are* spaceship designs that would have intake manifolds, or something similar; for instance, the [Bussard Ramjet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet) uses large electromagnetic fields to gather interstellar hydrogen, which it uses for fuel.

It's entirely possible that the insectoids used a similar method which relies on gathering interstellar hydrogen (or what have you) for their engines; the stuff that is gathered will normally be at about [space temperature](http://www.universetoday.com/77070/how-cold-is-space/), so running a hot plasma through the system may cause issues.

This is of course aside from the ever-present "ignored their scientific adivisors" answer.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. But yes, most likely they use something involving something like a [Buzzard collector](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bussard_collector).

Comment: @Xantec [Bussard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_W._Bussard), not [Buzzard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzard) :)

Comment: Bussard on Federation ships maybe. But I bet the Kligons call them Buzzards.

Comment: @Xantec That's what Hamlet called them in the original Klingon!